# Crystal oscillator circuit not reaching full voltage

Tags: oscillator, crystal, z80

I want to generate a clock for a z80 CPU using a crystal oscillator but somewhere between 8 and 13.5mhz the  voltage drops and with 20mhz it's about 1 volt peak to peak. I have tried numerous circuits including the one below using a 74hc14 and a 74hcu04 with the same results , what could I be doing wrong?
[image: one of the circuits I tried]

Comment: What are you using to measure the voltage?  If scope, what is the bandwidth of the scope and probe?

Comment: I'm using an analog scope that can go up to 35mhz and I have some cheap eBay probes at 10x and they write 100mhz 600v on them

Comment: I suspect what you're seeing is the 35MHz bandwidth coming into play.

Comment: Would they advertise it as a 35 MHz scope if it altered the results on just 14 MHz? Or could it need calibration?

Comment: Look at the graph of a single pole, low pass rolloff characteristic.  If your scope and your probe combined are 35MHz BW, that means your displayed amplitude will be 70% of the actual amplitude for a 35MHz signal.  Perhaps someone reading this on more than their phone can answer properly with some graphics or a circuit sim.

Comment: I think you are right. I just connected the BNC center pin to the output of my circuit with a sort piece of wire and it goes up to 5 volts even on 20mhz

Comment: For the record, the original Z80 required its CLK input signal to get much closer to its VCC and GND supply pin voltages than the TTL levels the rest of its pins used. Later chips may have relaxed this requirement and I don't know which device you're using but it's something to check.

Comment: @TonyM I'm using a z84c0020pec and looking at the datasheet the clock high should be between vcc-0.6 to vcc+0.3. how could I check that if the voltage measurement from my oscilloscope could be inaccurate?

Comment: By 'check', I meant check the CLK voltage requirement in your datasheet. My comment wasn't about your 'scope voltage problem, just advisory.

Comment: @TonyM I know , it was a separate question although I'm pretty certain the problem is due to signal degradation

Comment: Oh, haven't a clue on that

Comment: @AlmostDone I believe your comment was the answer, do you want to post it as an answer or edit Andy aka's answer or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

> what could I be doing wrong?

Your schematic show a schmitt trigger as the oscillator's inverter - this is incorrect - it should be a fast unbuffered inverting device for this circuit to work correctly and accurately.

Comment: Isn't the 74hcu04 unbuffered? I believe I read somewhere that it is. Anyway, the problem was my probes . Apparently higher frequencies can result in lower voltage reading